# MagicalRecord 3.0 not saving. No objects for the second build

Tags: ios, xcode, magicalrecord

I am trying out MagicalRecord 3.0 for the first time and I can't make it work.

This is what I am doing.

1- Setup stack:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[MagicalRecord setupClassicStackWithSQLiteStoreNamed:@"Model"];}
```

My model name is "Model.xcdatamodeld".

2- Create entities and Save:

```
Preferences *p = [Preferences createEntity];
p.visibilityWindow = @"08:00-23:30";

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"You successfully saved your context.");
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

3- Load data:

```
NSArray *matches;

NSError * error = nil;
matches = [Preferences MR_findAll];

Preferences *p = nil;

NSLog(@"Fetch request data %@",matches);
if(!matches || error || ([matches count] >1)){
    //handle error;
    NSLog(@"Error %@ matches count %lu", error, (unsigned long)[matches count]);
}else if ([matches count]){
    p = [matches firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Preferences found in coredata %@", p);
}else{
    NSLog(@"No matches %i", [matches count]);
}
```

I am also "Cleaning up" as the documentation suggests:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];
```

}

It was working totally fine when I was using the traditional core data framework.

It says that I am saving successfully. But when I quit the app and try to run it again it doesn't work anymore. 
**What am I doing wrong**?

Also, from the posts I read, everyone talks about a "MR_defaultContext". Was it deprecated?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:
Looking at the code for MagicalRecord 3.0, `MR_context` returns a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.  Using `MR_createEntity` appears to use a different, main queue context.  Try creating your entity with `MR_createEntityInContext:` and passing in `MR_context`.

Also, without knowing when you are calling each of the three methods, try using `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWaitWithError:`.

EDIT:
Probably the quickest thing to do to test is to change step 2:

```
Preferences *p = [Preferences createEntity];
p.visibilityWindow = @"08:00-23:30";

NSError *error; // add this
BOOL success = [p.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithError:error] // change this
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"You successfully saved your context.");
} else if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error.description);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Doesn't return from creating the Entity. Doesn't even reach the save method. Will try to save in the main queue context instead.

Comment: I should also point out that `MR_findAll` ALSO uses a different, main queue context, so if you are still using `MR_context` you will need to call `MR_findAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]]` instead.

Comment: I think in 3.0 you want to use `[[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] context]`.  That appears to be the equivalent to the old `MR_defaultContext`.

Comment: This last comment worked. Thank you very much @Aaron !! You may edit the actual answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... there is that I used (with your stuff) also I add the option to store with [UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Saving-Entities#handling-long-running-saves) (opcional)

--

```
Preferences *p = [Preferences createEntity];
p.visibilityWindow = @"08:00-23:30";

[SomethingManagerObject saveIntoContext]
```

--

SomethingManagerObject

```
+ (void) saveWithContext{

//  THIS IS opcional!!! -> Prepar for BackgroundTask
UIApplication * application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

//  Get the context
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] context];

// Save the modification in the context
[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}];
}
```

Or you can save with managedObjectContext of the entity. In `saveWithContext` method just add parameter and send the `p.managedObjectContext`. Inside change `[[MagicalRecordStack defaultStack] context]`

The SomethingManagerObject is a NSObject that you can use to have class methods like that... save...create...